# Accessing a field/variable of a recycler viewholder(listItem) in Activity/Fragments

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am using recyclerview to display multiple view types, however I am trying to find a possible way to access the viewholder/listItem  field/variable from the activity/fragment. Like in my case I have 3 viewholder (one for image, one for text , one for video).

Thank you. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 public class VideoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {//0
        final TextView tv,name,time,caption,allcomments,likescount,commentcount;

        final ImageView img_vol, img_playback, overflow, imagehear, share, image_sent_friendReq, profile_image, send_friendReq, chat;

        final PlayerView player;

        public SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;

        public VideoHolder(View x) {
            super(x);
            tv = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.tv);
            img_vol = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.img_vol);
            img_playback = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.img_playback);
            overflow = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.overflow);
            name = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.name);
            time = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.time);
            caption = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.caption);
            imagehear = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.image_heart);
            share = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.share);
            allcomments = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.view_all_comments);
            likescount = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.likes_count);
            commentcount = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.comment_count);
            image_sent_friendReq = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.image_sent_friendReq);
            profile_image = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.profile_image);
            send_friendReq = ButterKnife.findById(x, image_send_friendreq);
            chat = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.chat);
            player = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.player);

            mediator = new Mediator(mCtx);
            SharedPreferences pref = mCtx.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            UID = pref.getString("UserID", "");

            if(fragment.equals("FriendsFragment")){
                send_friendReq.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                image_sent_friendReq.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else if(fragment.equals("ProfileActivity")){
                send_friendReq.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                chat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                overflow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                allcomments.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else {
                chat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        //override this method to get callback when video starts to play
//        @Override
//
//        @Override
//        public void pauseVideo() {
//            super.pauseVideo();
//            img_playback.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
//        }
    }
```

Fragment:

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        unbinder.unbind();

        //Release the player
//        ((MyVideosAdapter.VideoHolder)RecyclerView.ViewHolder).simpleExoPlayer.release();
        for(int position = 0; position<modelList.size(); position++){
            if(mAdapter.getItemViewType(position)== MyVideosAdapter.TYPE_VIDEO){

            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by access, are you trying to pass some value or want to listen to user actions on those views?

Comment: Trying to access that particular viewholder field's value, like can I typecast or is there any other way round.

Comment: Posting your custom Adapter class would be more of help. Anyway, I'm providing a draft version to accomplish it. `if (adapter.getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO){ ((VideoObject)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).getVideoName()}`.

Comment: @Farid Thanks , i've done the changes , have a look at my code and adapter which i am trying to access, Actually i want to release the exoplayer instance on destroy and pause methods in the fragment itself.

Answer (score 0):

we have use interface to Assess RecyckerView Fields and variables .see code snippet . in this code i have used a interface to communicate with activity/Fragment. i have pass recycler view item value to activity on item click

Like this

**Interface**

```
public interface TrackItemOnclick {
    public  void onItemClick(View view,int position,String userType);
}
```

**HomeActivity**

```
 customAdapter = new CustomAdapter (getActivity(), dataList, new TrackItemOnclick() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position,String userType) {
                    String date=CommonUtils.getTodayDate();
                    Log.e(TAG,"check data"+userType);
                    //go to detail screen

                }
            });
```

**CustomAdapter**

`constructor`

```
public TodayAdapter(Context context, List<TracksBeen.Data.Today> tracklist, TrackItemOnclick onclick) {
        this.context = context;
        this.tracklist = tracklist;
        this.onclick = onclick;
    }

 //onclick listner
        myholder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onclick.onItemClick(v, i,tracklist.get(i).getTrackRaceIsGuestAvailable());
            }
        });
```